# Creating database in microcontroller

Tags: embedded

I have a project using pic18f mcu. I need to make database in this macho, but I don't know how doing it. Databases are done through SQL but I don't know how making it though. If someone can give me a start point. 
Hint: database I am trying to create is simple and it only consists of one column (mac address) and it can be updated. If there is a way which is easier than creating a database I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: If you only want one value why do you need a database? How about a variable? Do you need it persistent? If so look to see if that part has some EEPROM or self programmable FLASH.

Comment: "I need to make database in this macho" Huh? Google translate?

Comment: SQL on a PIC18F!? Good luck with that!  Connecting to an SQL database hosted elsewhere from a PIC18 _client_ is one thing, hosting the database _on_ the PIC18 seems inappropriate.  SQL seems way over the top for your vaguely specified requirements in any case. moreover between specifying microcontroller and an SQL data base there is a great deal left unspecified - file-system, storage media, communication/interaction.  It is way too broad - you need to at least describe your board resources.

Comment: SQL for 8-bit MCU...I don't think so, considering the SQL thread requirements which needs an RTOS. Anyway, thhere is a SQL database product for embedded systems from [ITTIA](http://www.ittia.com/products/ittia-db-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which PIC18F are you using? If it is an older one, then you should use the on-board EEPROM, for the newer ones I recommend using the High Endurance Flash (HEF) on-board the microcontroller.

You could also look at using an external memory device if you don't want to use internal EEPROM or HEF.

If you are worried about I/O Microchip provides UNI/O serial EEPROM devicews EERAM devices that require a single I/O pint for reading and writing.

If you need unlimited writes as you will be updating the value many times a second, you can use Serial EERAM products from Microchip, they are nonvolatile, can be written to instantaneously and  have unlimited endurance.

Still if you insist on a database of some sort, you can always store data in a text file as CSV and then do processing on-board the uC to convert it to a tabular form that you can display to the user.

You have a lot of possibilites, it would depend on what exactly you application is. As for SQL, it isn't possible, as it isn't not needed in a uC application.